# Why won't my interference pattern go away?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, double-slit-experiment, interference, polarization

Bought a double slit diaphragm, laser pointer and some linear polarizing sheets off of Amazon so I could see the double slit experiment first hand.

When I place a vertically aligned polarizer in front of the left slit and a horizontally aligned polarizer in front of the right slit, I still get an interference pattern.

I'm certain it is set up correctly because when I check the setup by hold the diaphragm in front of my ceiling light and hold another polarizing sheet between my eyes and the diaphragm, every 90 degree turn blocks the light from one of the slits.

Shouldn't my polarizers be causing the interference pattern to disappear?

Comment: Did the intensity of the interference pattern change as the orientation of one of the Polaroid’s was changed?

Comment: You may be seeing a [single-slit interference pattern](http://hydrogen.physik.uni-wuppertal.de/hyperphysics/hyperphysics/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html). Block one of the slits completely and see if the pattern is the same.

Comment: @Farcher I'm not sure what you mean by intensity in this context. Brightness of the light?

Comment: @MarkH When I block one slit, the "bigger" (single slit) interference pattern remains, but the "smaller" interference pattern goes away.

Comment: Dos the overall brightness of the interference pattern change?

Comment: @Farcher Yes, it gets a little dimmer.

Comment: The other factor I can think of is the quality of the polarizers. Ideal polarizers result in light with exactly one polarization. However, non-ideal polarizers leave light only mostly polarized, such that crossed polarizers still let light through. To check this, look through two polarizers at a bright light such as a clear light bulb. Rotate the polarizers to find the minimum brightness. If you can see light at all orientations, then that might be the source of the problem. Both slits are still producing light that can interfere with light from the other slit.

Comment: As @MarkH has noted test the quality of your Polaroid’s with the light from your laser pointer.  I guess that the extinction is not perfect?

Comment: @MarkH Per your comments, I did a test to verify the polarizers are working as expected.  I re-rand the experiment, but this time put a 3rd polarizer just behind the polarized double-slit diaphragm.  Every 90 degree turn of that 3rd polarizer blocked the light from one slit or the other resulting in me losing double-slit interference and only seeing single-slit interference.

Comment: @Farcher I tried to add you to the comment above, but it would only let me comment to one person,

Comment: Try placing the polarizers after the slit.  ?   The Harvard paper is the best reference to this type of experiment: https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/27413728/single_photon_paper.pdf?sequence=4&isAllowed=y

Comment: Note the Harvard folks placed an additional polarizer just after the light source.